# Long document with two independetly running columns

Tags: adobe-indesign, page-layout

I am working on a translation a try to put the original and the translated text side by side in the document. I would like the columns to be independent and run over multiple pages, so that if I enter enough text to overflow one column, a new page is created that continues both columns. As a visualization, take a look at the [paracol environment of LateX](http://ftp.fau.de/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/paracol/paracol-man.pdf) or:

```
This is my first text            This is text 2 which
on page one it is                is also very long and
quite long                       should also break

[page break]---------------------------------------------

and continues on page            over to the next page
two and so on ...                and go on here.
And on ...                       And on ...
```

Since I have about 400 pages of text, I would like to automate this.

I tried to solve this with a master template and automatic text flow. However, if one column overflows and a new page is created, only one of the text fields is linked. This would mean that I need to link all 400 pages by hand. I would like to find a way around this, but all tutorials I found either relied on manual text flow (a lot of clicking and linking) or did just not work.

I have also created a spread master template with two columns per page and have linked the columns on the spread (left column on page 1 to left column on page 2, etc.) but copying the text again did not make the link carry over to the next spread.

Does anyone know how this behavior can be achieved?

Comment: The spread thing only works for primary text frames. I would imagine something like this would work: 1) make the left columns primary on master spread, 2) paste text and let it auto-reflow, 3) make right columns primary on master spread, 4) reapply master to pages (not sure if necessary), 5) paste translation into right column; should reflow automatically.

Answer (score -1):

Check out this article on InDesignSecrets

https://indesignsecrets.com/creating-two-or-more-automatic-text-flows.php

Comment: Your answer cannot be just a link, it should at least summarize that document.